# Mysql: Latest items grouped by a string

Tags: mysql, sql

a question to the mysql-pros:

I have some entrys in the database:

```
column a | column b | id
------------------------  
"xxxx" | Timestamp | 1
"yyyy" | Timestamp | 2
"xxxx" | Timestamp | 3
"yyyy" | Timestamp | 4
```

I wanna have the entries with the latest timestamp in column b grouped by the string in column a . So {1,3} and  {2,4} are group together (same "xxxx") and if 1 and 4 have the latest timestamp then the result should be {1,4}.

Select id,max(b) from myTable group by a  --> just gives me a "random" id with the latest timestamp. Maybe someone here knows a good solution?

tia && regards
 noircc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT a, GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM
   ( SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY b )
GROUP BY a
LIMIT 1
```

I'm not sure about timestamp values from your example, but you can order it before group_concat

Comment: +1 Include column a in the select clause, otherwise it won't be clear which ids correspond to which strings.